# What does "pale intelligence" mean here?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Could you please tell me what "intelligence" mean in the following sentence?

> As Giovanni followed her with his eyes, he beheld the emaciated figure
> and pale intelligence of Dr. Rappaccini, who had been watching the
> scene, he knew not how long, within the shadow of the entrance.
>
> Nathaniel Hawthorne, "Rappaccini's Daughter"

It seems to me that this "intelligence" means "face", but no dictionary that I checked lists such meaning. I appreciate it very much if you could explain.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a standard idiom or expression. Instead it is an "impressionistic" phrasing.  Somehow Dr. Rappaccini gives an impression of "pale intelligence".  I get the feeling of someone intelligent but narrow-minded, someone who is quiet and cold, even a little scary.  Someone who spends a lot of time inside studying.

The aim is to give us an impression of a certain type of intelligent person rather than a literal meaning like "face"